# How can I get maximal ideal containing an ideal using Macaulay2?

Tags: commutative-algebra, computational-algebra, macaulay2

In Macaulay2, I have written the following codes to find the maximal ideal in the ring $Q[x,y,z]$ containing the ideal generated by $x^2y+z$ and $xz-y$.

R=QQ[x,y,z]
I=ideal(x^2*y+z,x*z-y)
M=getMaxIdeal I

But every time I get the error code:

```
   error: no method for adjacent objects:<br>
```

getMaxIdeal (of class Symbol)
--                    2
--    SPACE   ideal (x y + z, x*z - y) (of class Ideal)

Please help me.

Comment: `primaryDecomposition I -- {ideal(z,y), ideal(y+z,x+1), ideal(x*z-y,y^2-y*z+z^2,x*y-y+z,x^2-x+1)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme $X\subseteq {\Bbb A}^3$ defined by the ideal $I=\langle x^2y+z,zx-y\rangle$ is supported

```
R=QQ[x,y,z]
I=ideal(x^2*y+z,z*x-y)
minimalPrimes I -- {ideal(z,y), ideal(x+1,y+z), ideal(x^2-x+1,-x*z+y)}
```

on the lines $y=z=0, x+1=y+z=0,$ and the lines $x^2-x+1=xz-y=0.$

The lines intersect as as follows:

```
minimalPrimes(ideal(z,y)+ideal(x+1,y+z)) -- {ideal(z,y,x+1)}
minimalPrimes(ideal(z,y)+ideal(x^2-x+1,-x*z+y)) -- {ideal(x^2-x+1,z,y)}
minimalPrimes(ideal(x+1,y+z)+ideal(x^2-x+1,-x*z+y)) -- {}
```

So $X$ has singular locus the three (1+2) points: `{ideal(z,y,x+1), ideal(z,y,x^2-x+1)}`. These give rise to the distinguished maximal ideals or points.

If you want any other points on the lines, just pick points on, say `ideal(z,y)`, by picking a third plane, say $x-a=0$, giving the maximal ideal,  say `ideal(z,y,x-a)` for any $a$ in your field.